# How to use the IObjectPool interface?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, pool, spring4d

I want to apply the IObjectPool from spring to my code in order to create a pool of objects (in my case, a thread class). Is there any example or documentation about the pools from spring?.

It's something like this:

```
TMyClass = class(TThread)
public
    constructor Create;
    procedure Execute; override;
end;
```

Another class:

```
uses
    ....
    Spring.Container,
    Spring.Container.Pool,
    Spring.Container.Core,
    Spring.Container.ComponentActivator,
    Spring.Services,
    ....;

TOtherClass = class
private
    FPool: IObjectPool;
    FActivator: IComponentActivator;
    ....
end;

implementation

constructor TOtherClass.Create;
begin
    FActivator := ServiceLocator.GetService<IComponentActivator>;
    FPool := TSimpleObjectPool.Create(FActivator, 5 , 10);
    FPool.Initialize(nil);
end;

procedure TOtherClass.AProcedure;
var
    task: TMyTask;
begin
    ...
    task := FPool.GetInstance(nil);
    ...
end;
```

I'm using XE6.

Regards.

Comment: I am missing the point where it says "this does not work because it returns nil" or "this raises exception xyz".